# How to debug nodejs with komodo IDE?

Tags: node.js, debugging, komodo-ide

I've created a project with komodo IDE:

[image]

I create debug config:

[image]

The program starts but dont stop at the breakpoint:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is there any step-by-step info for this? 
Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugger in nodejs never stops on single-lined app like this. When I have several lines like this, then it would work. Single-lined app exits too fast and debugger can't connect. This is obviously a bug in nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js only breaks on breakpoints when you run in debug mode.

Either with `node debug script.js` or `node --debug-brk script.js`.

Here you need to tell the IDE if needs to add the command line arguments to run the script.

Comment: how can I specify these properties? I've tried adding debug and --debug-brk to the "Interpreter arguments" edit box. It doesn't show selected line to be stopped at.

Comment: Adding debug to interpreter arguments should do the trick... I don't know what's going on then.